# Why does my .js Function not get attached to Element's Event Handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

The event listener (onClick event) never gets attached.

Any ideas?

MyPage.html  has:

```
  <p>
  <a href="#" class="js-expander expander">Learn more</a></p>  
  <div class="js-expander-content hidden"><p>
Hidden-text-goes-here </p>
            </div>
            <p />

            &nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

expander.js  is:

```
    /* expander control */
    debugger;  // THIS EXECUTES
        $().ready(function() {
    debugger;   //THIS NEVER EXECUTES


    $(document).on('click', '.js-expander', function(e){
        var e =  e || event, 
            $el = $(this), 
            $content;

        e.preventDefault();

        $content = $el.parent().next('.js-expander-content')
        if ($content.length == 0)
          $content = $el.parent().parent().next('.js-expander-content')
          if ($content.length == 0)
            $content = $el.siblings('.js-expander-content');

        $content.slideToggle(150);
      })
    })
```

Comment: Have you referenced the JQuery library and done so prior to your code?

Comment: Also, what jQuery version? `$()` was deprecated back in 1.4. Use `$(document)`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as JQuery is referenced correctly, your code will execute.

FYI - you do have several HTML syntax errors and you have some outdated and unnecessary JavaScript (i.e. `e = e || event`) unless you still need to support IE8.

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.js-expander', function(e){ 
        $el = $(this), 
        e.preventDefault();

        $content = $el.parent().next('.js-expander-content')
        if ($content.length == 0){
          $content = $el.parent().parent().next('.js-expander-content');
        }
        
        if ($content.length == 0){
            $content = $el.siblings('.js-expander-content');
        }

        $content.slideToggle(150);
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <a href="#" class="js-expander expander">Learn more</a>
</p>  
<div class="js-expander-content hidden">
    <p>Hidden-text-goes-here</p>
</div>
```